# Select rows with different value in same filed

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I am so good with sql so I need your help.

I have one table called property. Now I want to retrieve rows with different value in same field. I tried with **LIKE** and **AND** but not getting any result.

**TABLE:**

```
id    user_id   title    approved
--    -------   -----    --------
1     60        one      1 
2     60        one      1
3     60        one      1
4     60        two      1
5     60        three    1
```

**SQL QUERY:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `property`
WHERE `user_id` =60
AND `approved` =1
AND `title` like '%one%'
AND `title` like '%two%'
```

**I want this result:**

```
id    user_id   title    approved
--    -------   -----    --------
1     60        one      1 
2     60        one      1
3     60        one      1
4     60        two      1
```

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: why you don't want row number 5?

Comment: @fthiella Because I want to filter records with `one` and `two`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `title like '%one%' AND title like '%two%'` you looks for a title that have "one" and "two" together. and you want some with "one" OR "two"

```
SELECT *
FROM `property`
WHERE `user_id` =60
AND `approved` =1
AND (`title` like '%one%' OR `title` like '%two%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

> OR or ||

condition. You are using LIKE condition to retrieve result.

That will retrieve If title have SIXTYONE also.

Because SIXTYONE contains "ONE" word. If you exactly looking for that, use LIKE as your post mentioned. else You should use =(equal to) for exact result. who having title "ONE" only. Can you try it?

```
SELECT *
FROM `property`
WHERE `user_id` =60
AND `approved` =1
AND (`title`='one' || `title`='two')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: You should explain what your answer fixes, instead of including only the code. Code-only answers are not encouraged as they don’t exactly help future readers (nor the askee), and are prone to get deleted.

Comment: @Smar Is it okay now?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM property
WHERE user_id =60
AND approved =1
AND title in('one', 'two')
```

since you already have fixed title, your error is title cannot like one and two at the same time :)